# command line to wait for input and then process next step

Tags: powershell, cmd, exe

I am writing a batch script to automate some processes.
this process runs a few different tools by stages, those tools creates the input necessary to run the next stage.

In one of the stages basically I open an .exe file and call a powershell file to simulate the "enter key" press, so far so good, it opens the tools and it starts to run run it, however what happens is that command line executes the next stage without waiting for the .exe file to finish, which is a important step thus that process creates the input for the next stage.

the command line I use is:

```
START /WAIT powershell -command .\bat.ps1
```

which runs this powershell script

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\folder\file.exe", "C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode")

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

I would like to know if there is a workaround that makes me wait till the .exe file finish running, and then start the new stage.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, that partially responds to my question.

I put the START /WAIT command after the powershell command, so while the `.exe` is running the next stage is on waiting, however I will have to press "y" to continue the process once the `.exe` file is finished, which is a start.

Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Start-Process` cmdlet and including the `-Wait` parameter in lieu of a direct call to Start()?

From your powershell prompt try `help start-process` to see if some of the other parameters like `-NoNewWindow` would also be useful to you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, 

I tried this one:
`Start-Process "C:\folder\file.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')`


unfortunately didn't execute the process

Comment: strange.  Are you sure the path to your process to start is correct?  What happens if you just type `Start-Process "L:\Daniel\PAF\New Processing\Workspaces\2A - Process PAF\file.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait` at the prompt?

Comment: yes, it opens the .exe file, but the script for the "enter key" pressing, is not working, so it doesn't run the tool. I would like to open the .exe file, press enter, and run the next stage once this stage is done.
thanks for your help, appreciate it

Comment: Are you trying to send the `Enter` key into `file.exe` for some reason?  Since you said `-Wait` that is never going to get a chance to run until the the `file.exe` process ends.   But it sounds like the `Enter` keystroke is what makes it end.  If this is the case then you will need `file.exe` to have a way to run in silent or quiet mode so no user input is needed.  You script can check the return code.

Comment: The `Enter` key is used to start the .exe file